# How to get window's scroll bars region?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have a list control and disable the scroll bar using the following code.

```
InitializeFlatSB(this->m_hWnd);
FlatSB_EnableScrollBar(this->m_hWnd, SB_BOTH, ESB_DISABLE_BOTH);
```

The scroll bars don't disappear, they just become white, which is what I need because I want to redraw my own scroll bars on their original rectangle region. In that way, my own scroll bars won't cover the list content and I can add functionality so that the mouse wheel function will be enabled.

But now how can I get the rectangle region of the scroll bars?

Comment: I know it's not your question, but if you want to remove them rather than disable them, you need [FlatSB_ShowScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775441(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @RogerRowland I want to disable them and redraw my own scroll bars on their original rectangle region. So my own scroll bars won't cover the list content and the mouse wheel function will be enabled.

Comment: Ok, I've taken the liberty of editing your question to make that clear - perhaps you can check if I've understood correctly and re-edit if necessary. Also, maybe you could look at [FlatSB_GetScrollProp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if that helps find the size of the scrollbars.

Comment: @RogerRowland Another question: The scroll bars are created as the list control's children. But when use `GetClientRect` to get the list rectangle region, we find that it does not include the scroll bars region. And we can't show a children control outside its parent's region.

Comment: Does `GetWindowRect` get what you want?

Comment: @RogerRowland `GetWindowRect` really can get the region inlcuding the scroll bars. But as mentioned above, we can't show a children control outside its parent's `client` region.

Comment: Ok then I suggest you update your question - you *can* now find the rects, but you want to be able to draw in the non-client area. This is now a different problem and may already have an answer.

Comment: Your assumption, that the scrollbars are child windows of the list control is wrong. [There are two types of scrollbars](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/10/129068.aspx), and these are the latter kind. Your options are to either override the `WM_NCPAINT` message, or create real scrollbar controls of your liking.

Comment: @IInspectable You mean that the scroll bars and the list control are independent to each other. And we should build the scroll bars as the list's siblings and link them in some way.

Comment: That's what I described as the second option. It's doable, but non-trivial. You should probably ask a new question, as it is unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, can you try to deduce the rectangle from GetWindowRect and GetClientRect? It seems to be a easy calculation to do subtractions and get a Non Client rectangle for the Vertical scroll bar and another for the Horizontal.